# Nav bar opens all icon menus in their respective location simultaneously

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, navbar

This code snippet is my nav bar for an admin user. The intended behavior is that there are 3 icons (navigation menu, user menu, and manage button icons). The issue is that the drop down items from each of these icons all display (In their respective location) when clicking on any of the icons. The intended behavior is to get each dropdown menu to display the selected information for that given icon.

```
  function NavbarAdmin() {
  const classes = navbarStyle();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const isNavMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isProfileMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isManageMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl('profileMenu');
  };

  const handleNavMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl('navMenu');
  };

  const handleManageMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl('manageMenu');
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const userMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={'profileMenu'}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Sign Out</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  const navMenu = (
    <Menu
    anchorEl={'navMenu'}
    anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'left' }}
    keepMounted
    transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'left' }}
    open={isMenuOpen}
    onClose={handleMenuClose}
  >
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Home</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Movies</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Concessions</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Showtimes</MenuItem>
  </Menu>
  );

  const manageMenu = (
    <Menu
    anchorEl={'manageMenu'}
    anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
    keepMounted
    transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
    open={isMenuOpen}
    onClose={handleMenuClose}
  >
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Movies</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Seats</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Test</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Test</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Test</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Test</MenuItem>
  </Menu>
  );

return (
    <div className={classes.grow}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start" className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="nav account"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={handleNavMenuOpen}
            color="inherit"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.acptheater} variant="h6" noWrap>
            ACP Theater
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.grow} />
          <div>
            <IconButton aria-label="show messages" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={1} color="secondary">
                <MailIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              edge="end" className={classes.menuButton}
              aria-label="user account"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
            <Button 
              edge="end" className={classes.menuButton}
              aria-label="user account"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleManageMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"color="inherit"
            >
                Manage</Button>
            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {manageMenu}
      {navMenu}
      {userMenu}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: They are all being controlled by the same `isMenuOpen` variable.

Comment: This is a new/additional question from the previous: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174542/nav-bar-opens-all-menus-simultaneously-upon-clicking

Comment: @RyanCogswell how do I alleviate this, I have tried creating 3 distinct "isMenuOpen" constructs, and the problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

`anchorEl` contains a string with the name of the desired (clicked on) menu.  It is a string - you cannot Boolean it.

So you need to test the variable containing the name of the menuToBeOpened (or, let's call it the "activeMenu"). *(I've renamed the variable from `anchorEl` to `activeMenu` because I see in your code that `anchorEl` is a Material-UI attribute and I don't know how that will affect Material-UI - so let's just use a different variable for that purpose...)*

Something like *(my code is untested, but that's the general principle)*:

```
const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = React.useState(null);

const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setActiveMenu('profileMenu');
};
const handleNavMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setActiveMenu('navMenu');
};
const handleManageMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setActiveMenu('manageMenu');
};
const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setActiveMenu(null);
};
```

And then, in the return:

```
return (
    //your other code...

    {activeMenu === 'profileMenu' && (
        <Menu
          anchorEl={'profileMenu'}
          anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
          keepMounted
          transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
          open={isMenuOpen}
          onClose={handleMenuClose}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Sign Out</MenuItem>
        </Menu>

    )}
    {activeMenu === 'navMenu' && (
        <Menu
        anchorEl={'navMenu'}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'left' }}
        keepMounted
        transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'left' }}
        open={isMenuOpen}
        onClose={handleMenuClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Home</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Movies</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Concessions</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Showtimes</MenuItem>
      </Menu>

    )}
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this presented the same issue as before also.

Comment: Please take another look, Alex. Look more closely at the underlying principle. The variable allows you to control whether the component will render in the `return()`. Get it working, then massage the working code to look/behave as you truly desire. In your previous question, you were using `anchorEl` to determine which menu item to make active - perhaps that variable should also be renamed to `activeMenu` ? Again, I am unsure what the attribute `anchorEl` does in Material-UI...